# Can you telnet to ssh?

Tags: http, tcp, ssh, telnet

I know you can telnet and negotiate with HTTP server by using HTTP protocol standards - for example:

```
telnet google.com 80
Trying 173.194.70.139...
Connected to google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP.1.1
HOST: my.com
```

and I get in response:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 925
Date: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 19:17:26 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
```

but my question is could I do the same with the SSH protocol?

Comment: what is the reason you want to do this ?

Comment: In effort of successfully fuzzing SSH port listener i need to know even a basic standard header the server is waiting for

Comment: found the answer: "SSH-2.0-billsSSH_3.6.3q3<CR><LF>"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SSH : SSH-protoversion-softwareversion SP comments CR LF

Example : 
    SSH-2.0-billsSSH_3.6.3q3

Found at : http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/rfc/rfc4253.txt

Answer (score 15):

Try hitting an SSH server with telnet on port 22. You get the first message, but nothing else that's useful. Just a "Protocol Mismatch" and the connection closes.

A telnet client is useful as a tool in this way because it uses a plain-text protocol. You can hit whatever port is using a different plain-text protocol and decode it in your head, as with HTTP. SSH encrypts everything, so using telnet to connect to an SSH server would prove a little hard to read with the naked eye.

```
telnet yoursshserver 22
Trying 50.112.5.74...
Connected to yoursshserver.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
something I typed
Protocol mismatch.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: so, no options to insert the header the SSH protocol is waiting for ?

Comment: You'd need to encode, by hand, the encrypted protocol stuff. I'm really not sure why you would want to do this - every bit of data is going to have to be sent encrypted, and decrypted coming back. Are you just in a place where you can't install an SSH client? I'd recommend using http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/ rather than trying to do this yourself. Putty also supports telnet...

Comment: In effort of successfully fuzzing SSH port listener i need to know even a basic standard header the server is waiting for

Comment: If you're doing this programmatically, then the questions that come to mind are: what language platform are you working with, and are there any libraries that can help out. Otherwise have a look at the code for the ssh client provided by the openSSH project.

Comment: found the answer: "SSH-2.0-billsSSH_3.6.3q3<CR><LF>"